# Fourier transform as the integral of a parameter multiplied by an homogeneous wave

Tags: fourier-transform

Can a Fourier transform in space be interpreted as the integral of a parameter multiplied by an homogeneous wave $\sigma$?

where $\sigma$ is:

$\sigma$=$e^{-ikx}$

Are there papers or book that illustrates this interpretation?

Comment: I mean, the fourier transform very literally is an integral of a function times a complex oscillation. I think you're using terms I'm not aware of – what's the *exact definition* of "homogenous wave"? What is your exact definition of "parameter"?

Comment: Point is: the Fourier transform is really well-defined. Whether or not it can be interpreted as something else depends on the really well-defined other thing. Please deliver that definition! Everything else would just lead to handwaving. If you can't define the other thing, then anything can be interpreted as the other thing (here: homogenous wave), and we have no interesting answer to give.

Comment: sorry... I just added the definition inthe question

Comment: For reference: Fourier Acoustics: Sound Radiation and Nearfield Acoustical Holography, which explains spatial Fourier transform in different coordinates.

Answer (score 1):

given your definition, and the definition of the Fourier transfer:

yes. That is literally the definition:

$$\int_{\mathbb R} s(x) e^{i2\pi f x} \mathrm dx$$

By comparison, with $k= 2\pi f$, you get the Fourier transform. Every book uses that definition, so you'll find this "interpretation" in every book that introduces the Fourier transform. (This really feels like exactly the same $k$-space / location transform I learned in my first solid state physics lecture, so I assume every modern solid state course for physicists does pretty much that, but more in-depth.)

Comment: $k=2πf/U$ where U is the propagation velocity